# MongoDB: search through arrays by value and by operator(s)

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a document like this:

```
{
  tags: ['a', 'b']
}
```

I want to find all documents that have only the tag `a`. My current query criteria is:

```
{
  tags: {
    $size: 1,
    $in: ['a']
  }
}
```

Is there a way to query using an `equal` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although queries on array fields implicitly check array values, you can also match the entire array. Consider the following example, which has a mix of strings and arrays of strings in the `tags` field:

```
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502943541f5b0d2bca9663a8"), "tags" : [ "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502943581f5b0d2bca9663a9"), "tags" : [ "a", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5029435e1f5b0d2bca9663aa"), "tags" : [ [ "a" ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502943641f5b0d2bca9663ab"), "tags" : [ [ "a" ], "b" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5029436c1f5b0d2bca9663ac"), "tags" : [ [ "a" ], [ "b" ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502943a31f5b0d2bca9663ad"), "tags" : [ "a", [ "b" ] ] }
```

Querying for `"a"` in `tags` will match any array that contains `"a"` alone or in part:

```
> db.foo.find({tags: "a"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502943541f5b0d2bca9663a8"), "tags" : [ "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502943581f5b0d2bca9663a9"), "tags" : [ "a", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502943a31f5b0d2bca9663ad"), "tags" : [ "a", [ "b" ] ] }
```

Although not shown, if we had a `tags` field that was simply `"a"` (not an array, but the string value), it would certainly be matched as well.

Querying for `["a"]` in `tags` will match the documents containing only `"a"` in their `tags` field as well as any `tags` arrays containing the value `["a"]` (i.e. nested array):

```
> db.foo.find({tags: ["a"]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502943541f5b0d2bca9663a8"), "tags" : [ "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5029435e1f5b0d2bca9663aa"), "tags" : [ [ "a" ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502943641f5b0d2bca9663ab"), "tags" : [ [ "a" ], "b" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5029436c1f5b0d2bca9663ac"), "tags" : [ [ "a" ], [ "b" ] ] }
```

If you can safely assume your schema will only store strings in its `tags` array, this query might be more desirable than storing the array size in a separate field and adding that to your query criteria (also a viable solution, as Matt mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

Save the size of the `tags` array as a separate attribute and update it upon modification of the `tags` array:

```
// Document
{
  tags : ['a'],
  tags_size : 1
}

// Criteria
{ tags_size : 1, tags : 'a' }
```

Note that the `$size` operator is unable to make use of indexes.

Comment: yeah, but trying to avoid that. i would rather just use the `$in` operator.